# Why MMA cannot apply the correct style of unit?

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet, fonts

When I select

**Style-> Style-> DisplayFormulaNumbered**

> [image]

Then I type some formula show as below:

> [image]

I found that the font of formula is not **Times New Roman**,so I select the unit ,then  select **Style->Font**, which shows that the font of formula is **courier new**.

#### Question

How to revise this condtion? or is it the default style of **DisplayFormulaNumbered**

---

### Update

Thanks for *Sjoerd C. de Vries*'s  solution.

When I select

- Format > StyleSeet > Book > Textbook

then I select

- Format > Style > EquationNumbered

Lastly, I input some formula shown as below (it show the correct formula style)

> [image]

I looked up the definition of `EquationNumbered`,then I found a difference `DefaultFormatType -> TraditionalForm`

---

So I execute some operations as below

- Format > StyleSeet > Default
- Format > Edit StyleSeet
- copying the DisplayFormulaNumbered style definitions from the Default.nb parent
- [image]

However, the result of formula remains keep the font of `courier new`.

[image]

Comment: Which stylesheet are you using?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, the stylesheet is the `Default.nb` of *Mathematica*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the way it has been configured `DisplayFormula` creates cells with the structure `Cell[BoxData[...],...]` whereas what you preferably want (IMO) for displaying formaulas is `Cell[TextData[...],...]`.

So the first step would be to make this change to your private stylesheet:

```
DefaultFormatType->DefaultTextFormatType,
```

or you could also make the cell style inherit from the `Text` style:

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayFormula",StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
 CellMargins->{{66, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}},
 StripStyleOnPaste->True,
 DefaultFormatType->DefaultTextFormatType,
 HyphenationOptions->{"HyphenationCharacter"->"\[Continuation]"},
 LanguageCategory->"Formula",
 ScriptLevel->0,
 SingleLetterItalics->True,
 MenuSortingValue->1700,
 FontFamily->"Times",
 FontSize->14,
 FontColor->GrayLevel[0.2],
 UnderoverscriptBoxOptions->{LimitsPositioning->True}]
```

IMO the default input style formatting is an oversight or error given that this cell style is almost always used for, or to try and obtain, traditional form text formatting. In the screen grab below you can see on top a cell created with the default `DisplayFormula` style which has an underlying `Cell[BoxData[ ...` structure. After editing the stylesheet you create a new cell and begin typing and you have a `Cell[TextData...` structure (equation below).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you dig in the default stylesheet belonging to your notebook the definition of the DisplayFormula style form which the DisplayFormula is derived. On my WIndows 8 PC it looks like this:

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayFormula"],
 CellMargins->{{66, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}},
 StripStyleOnPaste->True,
 DefaultFormatType->DefaultInputFormatType,
 HyphenationOptions->{"HyphenationCharacter"->"\[Continuation]"},
 LanguageCategory->"Formula",
 ScriptLevel->0,
 SingleLetterItalics->True,
 MenuSortingValue->1700,
 FontFamily->"Arial",
 FontSize->14,
 FontColor->GrayLevel[0.2],
 UnderoverscriptBoxOptions->{LimitsPositioning->True}]
```

You can see that the base font type is Arial. However you also see the line

```
DefaultFormatType->DefaultInputFormatType
```

which seems to indicate the default display type is `InputForm`. This usually formats in a monospaced font such as Courier. Your formula will therefore look like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What you can do is change the format type to `TraditionalForm`. You can do that by selecting the `Cell>Convert to>TraditionalForm Display` menu item. Now your formula looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Checking the font using the Format menu confirms that this is indeed Arial as demanded in the stylesheet.

This is still different from a `TraditionalForm` formatted code input which looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

According to the font dialog this is indeed Times New Roman.

You can achieve this by copying the DisplayFormula and DisplayFormulaNumbered style definitions from the Default.nb parent of the private stylesheet of your notebook to this private stylesheet and opening the DisplayFormula definition using Cell>Show Expression (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and changing the above line to read

```
FontFamily->"Times New Roman"
```

Your formula now looks like this (in `TraditionalForm` display):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is pretty close. You probably need to copy some definitions from the `TraditionalForm` definition into the DisplayFormula definition to make it a perfect match.

Comment: Is it possible to make the formula show the result of `Times New Roman` font, not `Courier new` font. Namely, I didn't need to select the `Cell >Convert to >TraditionalForm Display` menu item.

Comment: Change the DefaultFormatType line to read DefaultFormatType->DefaultTextFormatType, see Mike's answer.

Comment: @ShutaoTang 1. When you change the StyleSheet make sure that you correctly saved the changed StyleSheet. Just to remind: to save the StyleSheet you cannot go to Menu/File/Save or do Ctrl+S. Instead you should do Menu/File/SaveAs. 2. In my case instead of changing the Default StyleSheet I created a custom one, a DefaultModified. In this one there are e.g., comfortably formatted DisplayFormula and DisplayFormulaNumbered and several other cell styles. May be it is a good idea to make your own style as I did.