# DisplayFormula badly rendered if style is set before writing

Tags: notebooks, formatting

If I have to write a display formula, I go to the cell after the text cell I'm currently into, select the `DisplayFormula` from the Style menu and then write. The result is the following
[image: Bad rendering]

I specifically set the `DisplayFormula` Style for this notebook to be also in the Palatino Linotype ([1] using the notebook stylesheet, see the next image) font face, but it seems to ignore this.
[image: Stylesheet]

Besides, I can turn a text cell into a display formula cell (font changing from Palatino to that one) but not viceversa: if I create a display formula cell, and then try to set its style to text, it simply won't.

[2]How can I get the `DisplayFormula` cell to use the font face selected in the stylesheet?

**EDIT 1**: I provided an image[1] showing where I set the style definitions and [2]better explained my question.

**EDIT 2**: The code used for the equation is

```
Cell[BoxData[
RowBox[{
  OverscriptBox["\[Rho]", "\[Tilde]"], "=", 
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{"(", 
    RowBox[{
     SubscriptBox["\[Sigma]", "y"], "\[CircleTimes]", 
     SubscriptBox["\[Sigma]", "y"]}], ")"}], 
   SuperscriptBox["\[Rho]", "*"], 
   RowBox[{"(", 
    RowBox[{
     SubscriptBox["\[Sigma]", "y"], "\[CircleTimes]", 
     SubscriptBox["\[Sigma]", "y"]}], ")"}]}]}]], "DisplayFormula",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.638208958864182*^9, 3.6382090127973466`*^9}, {3.6382096101377*^9, 3.6382096430745516`*^9}, {
  3.638209806903561*^9, 3.6382098103408413`*^9}}]
```

while for the style definition

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayFormula"],
 FontFamily->"Palatino Linotype",
 FontSize->14,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Plain",
 FontVariations->{"StrikeThrough"->False,
 "Underline"->False}]
```

For the sake of clarity, *I'm on Windows 8.1, using Mathematica 10*.

Comment: Could you detail how precisely you set the font type for the DisplayFormule style?

Comment: It is not clear, what is your question. It is since the question staying in the end of your text has a trivial answer: "Yes, you do, all of us do". But may be the real question is how to achieve the DisplayFormula format of your wish?

Comment: The equation you're displaying has no 'normal' letters. Might the problem be that mathematical symbols are taken from Mathematica's own fonts as they probably won't be available in the Palatino font set?

Comment: The image, itself, is not enough. Could you post the code used? You view it using cmd-shift-E (cntrl on windows).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries that's not the problem because even using simple latin letters results in the same font being displayed.

Comment: @rcollyer I'm updating the question with the code.

Comment: A related (or duplicate) post: [why-mma-cannot-apply-the-correct-style-of-unit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70241/why-mma-cannot-apply-the-correct-style-of-unit)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries yes, it actually solved my problem. Thanks!